# java.nio.file Files.isWritable not working with network shared drives

Tags: java, java.nio.file

I have a java application that write files on given location. 
Before writing I am checking if provided path is writable by using **Files.isWritable(path)**.

When user is giving the path of folder that is present in network shared drive.
Then getting **AccessDeniedException**.

Don't know whats happening, am I missing something. Because I am able to create/edit/delete  files and folders on shared drive.

But with java application unable to do so.

While searching for some answer found this
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034057
Don't know if its related to my issue.

Can anyone help me with this issue and tell me whats going wrong.

Have also checked with network team. I have full read write permission on shared drive.

**Java version 1.8.0_191**

**OS- Win 7 enterprise**

This is my code for checking

```
private static boolean isWritable(Path path)
{
    if(Files.isWritable(path))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))
        {
            // NOP
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
            {
                LOGGER.debug("", e);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Attached the image. So basically I cannot create file in any of the 4 shared drive i.e. I/O/R/S drives But I am able to create in C/D drive. Manually I am able to but with java program I am not.
[image]

Comment: Please specify: which client OS? which server OS? which type of network share?

Comment: Just get rid of the test. The `IOException` that is thrown if you can't open the file for writing when you actually need to write to the file tells you exactly the same thing, much more reliably, and without the false positive and timing-window problems of this code. In general by far the best way to tell whether any resource is available for any use is to try to use it in that way, and deal with the errors or exceptions as they arise. What you are engaged in here basically constitutes trying to predict the future.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder Its Window 7 enterprise. About Network share will check once with the network team. Since the system what I am using is not in my location Its at client location and we use it remotely. So about network sharing details will take bit time. And not sure If I can get answers.

Comment: You say you're not sure if the bug report you mention is related to your issue. That bug report concerns SUBSTed drives. Are you using SUBST?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. For me, isWritable behaves as expected: `Files.isWritable(Paths.get("\\\\server\\Share\\MyFolder"))` returns true, while `Files.isWritable(Paths.get("\\\\server\\Share\\TheCEOsFolder"))` returns false. What is your exact Path specification? Maybe there's an error in how you've specified it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Have attached the image of shared drives in post.Please take a look. Its not the normal share folder that we share with anyone. And I am not that network expert so don't know those drives are SUBST drives or.

Comment: It's impossible to tell if any of those drives are SUBST drives or not. You can find out by typing SUBST in a Command Prompt window. Also, what are the actual values of the `path` argument? Can you put a `System.out.println(path);` (or similar) in your method and show the output? (Change the names of the folders to make them anonymous, but leave all special characters such as `:` and `\\ ` intact.)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I think its not SUBST drive. Since while typing SUBST in command prompt it didn't listed any. Also for accessing I use drive letters, its just like normal drive e.g path for I drive will be like this "I:\Test\dir". Don't use "\ \"

Comment: But do you have `"I:\Test\dir"` as a literal string inside your Java source code? Or do you enter this directory in a text box when the program runs? I'm asking because the backslash is an escape character in Java; so `"I:\test"` is actually `"I:<TAB>est"`. If you print out the path, you'll see if it looks right.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException We have directory selector in application from there user have to select the directory. I have debug and check , path comes as it is like "I:\Test\dir" and we pass it to Files.isWritable(path). I am checking with network teem too to see if this might be some permission issue. Means the application what we are using should have write permission into those drives.